# How to check what url is loaded?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside

I have a code that looks similar to this:

```
class A(QWebView):
    def __init__(self):
        # some code here
        # in here I want to check what url is loaded and based on that assign appropriate SLOT
        # I was wondering how to do something like that:
        # if 'examle.html' in self.url():
        #     self.loadFinished.connect(self.example)
        # else:
        #     self.loadFinished.connect(self.anotherSLOT)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    br = A()
    br.load(QUrl('http://example')
    br.show()
    app.exec_()
```

I have a feeling that I'm doing it completely wrong. Ideally I would like to load both urls and connect it to appropriate slot, but for now I come up with only this kinda solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you get the current url with:

```
self.url().toString()
```

you can then check with:

```
    if 'example' in self.url().toString() \
    or self.url().toString().endswith('example') \ 
    or 'example' in self.url().toString().split("/"):
        pass
```

Comment: You right, it works. but unfortunately it doesn't give me the right result, so it doesn't check the url

Comment: is `'http://example'` the url you are loading? cause it redirects to [http://www.iana.org/domains/example/](http://www.iana.org/domains/example/), you could then check with `if self.url().toString().endswith('example/')`